# Using bash to find strings in text files where the case DOES NOT match

Tags: string, bash, grep, find

I have a list of hundreds of mixed-case filenames in `~/script-filenames`, and hundreds of text files to search, in the current directory, that may contain these filenames.

Currently I am using the following 2 commands:

1. To return all matches regardless of case:

   ```
   xargs -0 -I @ -a ~/script-filenames grep -ri @
   ```
2. To return all exact matches:

   ```
   xargs -0 -I @ -a ~/script-filenames grep -r @
   ```

But how would I find strings that match when case is ignored but fail when case is exact?

Perhaps there is a way using egrep and regexp, but I don't know how.

Comment: `grep -r @`  what do you want to grep? nothing?

Comment: No, xargs declares @ as a substitution variable for the tokens in the input file.

Comment: yes, then your command is something like `grep -r filename` right? where is the pattern?

Comment: Well, it's supposed to but looks like it didn't...

Comment: No   grep -r mystring    looks for mystring in all files from the current location and prints lines that are matching. What I did wrong is use the -0 option to xargs rather than clean up the input file. xargs -I allows you to declare a substitution variable for use elsewhere in the cmdline. I used @ as my substitution variable.

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround for your problem may be the use off diff:

```
xargs -0 -I @ -a ~/script-filenames grep -ri @ >hitList.IgnoredCase
xargs -0 -I @ -a ~/script-filenames grep -r @ >hitlist.WithCase

diff -u hitList.IgnoredCase hitlist.WithCase|grep ^+ |cut -c 2-
```

The output of the diff line will contain only the lines with inexact case.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using diff, something along these lines was helpful once I had sensibly comparable data.